# How to implement a count-down Timer on a Web Site

Tags: javascript, timer, dom-events, settimeout, setinterval

I want to get an website element that is always changing, such as a countdown timer that resets when someone clicks on a button. Anyone know how I can implement a constantly changing element in my C# program?

Comment: Can you provide some information of what you trying to do and what framework you are using ("C# program sounds like WinForms/WPF, but "website element" sounds like ASP.Net)... Also if it is web site what browsers you are looking for to support and if code must be done in C# (SignalR comes to mind) or basic duplicate of some JS question would work as an asnwer?

Comment: And, if you're as new as it sounds like, you should be told that you can't "constantly" change the website element from the server - you have to change it on the client (in the browser).

Comment: Let me try to add some clarity. If by 'changing web element' you mean something constantly updating like the digital clock at the bottom of this sample page (link: http://webinfocentral.com/), then you can use either setInterval() or setTimeout() Javascript functions. Best regards,

Comment: thanks for your reply, and yes im new. im using c# winforms and would like to display a countdown timer thats on a website on my winform.

Comment: It's a bit unclear: why do you need a website on your winform to implement the timer? Could you please clarify what is your project" WPF application, WinForm application, or a Website? Just in case, here is a link to simple digital clock implemented in Web Page: http://digiclock.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The countdown timer is on an auction website, each time someone bids the countdown timer resets. I only want to bid once the timer hits a specific number.

Comment: I have posted the answer to you question (sample digital clock): you can modify it slightly to implement a count-down timer. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement periodic updates using client-site Javascript functions, either `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`, with syntax like following:

```
// start digital clock
function StartTopClock() { _pID = window.setInterval('UpdateTopClock()', 100);}
```

which provides periodic updates every 100 ms.
Detailed description is available at: http://digiclock.codeplex.com/, working demo at: http://webinfocentral.com/

Hope this will help. Best regards,